# SQL Server Indexed View Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexed-view

I realize this is a very contrived example, but I've simplified the full version down to the following which demonstrates the problem:

```
CREATE VIEW model.Appointments_Partition1
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15), AppointmentId) as Id, 
         ap.AppTypeId as AppointmentTypeId, 
         ap.Duration as DurationMinutes, 
         ap.AppointmentId as EncounterId, 
         COUNT_BIG(*) as __count_big
    FROM dbo.Appointments ap 
    JOIN dbo.PracticeCodeTable pct ON SUBSTRING(pct.Code, 1, 1) = ap.ScheduleStatus 
                                  AND pct.ReferenceType = 'AppointmentStatus' 
   WHERE ap.AppTime > 0
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(15), AppointmentId), ap.AppTypeId, ap.Duration, ap.AppointmentId

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Appointments_Partition1_Id]
ON model.Appointments_Partition1 ([Id]);
```

I get:

> Msg 8668, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
>       Cannot create the clustered index 'IX_Appointments_Partition1_Id' on view 'PracticeRepository.model.Appointments_Partition1' because the select list of the view contains an expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column. Consider removing expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column from select list.

I'm including count_big...so why is the group by a problem?....and how can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the same error message with some boolean logic applied to it:

> Cannot create the clustered index '...' on view '...' because the
>   select list of the view contains **an expression on a grouping column**.
>   Consider removing expression on a grouping column from the select list.

You need to remove the `CONVERT` in `CONVERT(varchar(15), AppointmentId)`

Answer (score -1):

I find this reason on one of the blogs, seems reasonable to me

> No, you can't use schema binding on a view that has an aggregate.  And you can't index a view unless you use schema binding.  You also can't bind an index that uses outer or left joins.  Basically, you can only bind a view that contains a simple select statement.

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1401646

You can go through the blog and see if it exactly matched your scenario.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

If you want to build index on views, then you must create views with schema binding, in the above link it is explained in detail. Go through the section of Design Considerations

Comment: That's not correct according to this: "If the view definition uses an aggregate function, the SELECT list must also include COUNT_BIG (*)." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: @JeffN825 please see above edited answer. Thats correct for simple views, but inorder to build index on views, you need to use schema binded views. Problem is not in aggregate functions, its in the index on the view.

Comment: it is schema binded. look at the question

Comment: @JeffN825 Sorry, my bad..
If problem is not yet solved, I was going through the link of technet and it is stated there that View definition should not contain CONVERT (producing imprecide result), although does not matched 100% with your case, but no harm in trying..